# Support for 802.1x Authentication in a device not supporting it earlier

Tags: linux, authentication

I am working on an embedded system with linux kernel 2.6.10 which is not supporting 802.1x authentication mode in wired network. It will be helpful if there are any specific pointers on how to proceed to have this authentication. And wanted to know whether it is sufficient to change kernel level driver (upgrade it) or will it need changes from the Application layer also? (Atleast from the protocol specifications about IEEE 802.1x my understanding is this authentication happens at lower layer itself)
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is updating the kernel not an option?

Comment: After some research i was able to find something on this topic again. My system is working on m68k processor. And as per this link i just need to have a wpa_supplicant as my device is going to be a supplicant in the complete system i am yet to try this out this weekend but please let me know in case this is not sufficient                    http://lxr.post-tech.com/source/external/wpa_supplicant/?a=m68k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer for this. I needed to have wpa_supplicant with its dependancies to be built. I was able to build and cross compile them successfully.